# how to open a new cmd.exe in C++ program and get its handle

Tags: c++, winapi, cmd, handle

I have a program running from a cmd.exe on Windows. I want to open a second cmd.exe when the program starts. Then the program will receive data to process which come from stdin of cmd.exe, and data from program will come to stdout of cmd.exe.

The stdin and stdout of the two cmd.exe are independent. The program can also display information on the first cmd.exe. It is not redirect.

On linux, I can use proxy_openpt() and system("xterm -SX/X") to control input and output of the terminal.

I have tried createprocess() and pipe, but I do not know how to get handle of the second cmd.exe to receive its input.

Please help me, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: CMD is not a console or terminal; it's a console client application, no different from your own application. By default your standard I/O is connected to the console input and screen buffer. This console may have been inherited from CMD if it's your parent process, but that's the extent of CMD's involvement.

Comment: A process can only attach to a single console at a time, but you can spawn another instance of your application that's attached to a new console (i.e. the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` creation flag) . Then cooperate with it using IPC, which isn't limited to standard handles and pipes.

Answer (score 1):

Only one Windows Console can be associated with a single process on Windows.

However, you can certainly use some IPC to control another process which just acts as a second console for you. **Helios** over at cplusplus.com wrote a simple example of how to do just that some time ago: linky link at “[Extra consoles](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/17371/)”.

The code can be used as-is, but you can always use it to inform your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
start cmd.exe @cmd /k "Command
```

or:

```
start cmd.exe
start file.cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the handle from the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` struct that you use with `CreateProcess`.

[PROCESS_INFORMATION documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684873(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: TCHAR szCommandLine[] = TEXT("cmd");
BOOL bRet = ::CreateProcess( NULL, szCommandLine, NULL,  NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,  NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

I can get a new cmd.exe like this. You mean pi.hProcess is the handle of the new cmd.exe?